# How to use Qualcoomm Vuforia in combination with location based markers

Tags: android, augmented-reality

As far as I understood, Vuforia is a good starting point for developing AR-Applications on the Android Plattform.
The Docs for Simple Virtual Buttons are quite good, but how would one combine this with location based data?

For Example:
On the application level, both markers and location based data should be used; so one would need f.e. Vuforia and another component for integrating location based data.

To get a deeper insight of what should be possible, here is an example:

You go through a landscape were the phone can

1.) recognize its position and view location based points on the screen and

2.) recognize objects in your view and perform actions upon "touching" those (virtual buttons, I learned..)

So my final question is:

Do you know examples of frameworks or demo-apps, where such a task is being accomplished by tying Vuforia together with location based AR Product/Framework XYZ?

Please excuse me, If I am not as precise as needed-I searched SO, but (as far as I saw) there are no such questions already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for location based AR like wikitude Layar etc who draw poi based on location on camera view you have to get poi from different Api like openstreet ,twitter,etc after parsing and put these data on cameraview. sensor values and gps values are used.
to start with you can go through [Mixare](http://code.google.com/p/mixare/wiki/GettingStarted) code which is open source .
you can implement this code with Vuforia cameraview.
follow my ans **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13208268/1206201)** for details. Gud luck